# Where I can see how many questions, answers I edited, closed etc

Tags: support, statistics

On Stack Overflow, where I can see the count of how many question and answers I've edited, and how many votes given by me in order to close questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think either of those metrics are displayed anywhere in the UI. The last editor of a post is available in the data dump, so there's a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/335/my-edits-sw-and-copy-editor) to sum those, but it misses any edits you've made that were superseded by a later edit, and it doesn't use live data so it's missing any edits you've made since the last data dump. There's a similar query for [close voting](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/792/how-many-questions-have-i-helped-to-close)